# Regular expression substitution problem in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex

Trying to capitalize all tags and running into trouble with substitution. Any idea why "upperCaseString" method isn't working?

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableString *stringToCap = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<kaboom>stuff</kaboom>"];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(</?[a-zA-Z].*?>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSMutableString *modifiedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:stringToCap options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToCap length]) withTemplate:@"$1".uppercaseString]];

NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Produces: `<kaboom>stuff</kaboom>` when I expect `<KABOOM>stuff</KABOOM>`

Comment: FYI - the call to `uppercasedString` is being done of the `@"$1"` literal before being passed as an argument to `withTemplate`. In other words, it's not what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringByReplacingMatchesInString:options:range:withTemplate:` doesn't work like that, the type of the last argument is just `NSString` and the string you are passing is the result of the expression `@"$1".uppercaseString` – which is just `@"$1"`.

A possible algorithm (pseudo code):

```
for NSTextCheckingResult *match in [regex matchesInString:... options:... range:...] do
   extract the substring at match.range from modified string
   uppercase it
   replace the substring at match.range with uppercased result
```